# Reading DNG file with libraw and passing pixel data to Cimg for image manipulation

Tags: c++, cimg, raw, dng, libraw

I'm reading a DNG file on Android with libraw in C++ which works pretty fine.
I want to pass the pixel data to Cimg for manipulation purposes (rotating etc.).

The problem is that the image in Cimg looks weird.
I think that problem is that the original pixel data from libraw are stored in a different order than in Cimg. In libraw (due to the DNG file) its RGBGRGBGRGBG while Cimg stores the pixel data in the way RRRRRR....GGGGGGG....BBBBBB.
Does anyone know how to convert from RGBGRGBGRGBG to RRRRRR....GGGGGGG....BBBBBB?

Here are both images, on the left is dng file and on the right is tiff file exported from cimg (both imported into Photoshop).

Here is my code:

```
LibRaw rawProcessor;
rawProcessor.open_file("file.dng");
rawProcessor.unpack();
int  ret2=rawProcessor.dcraw_process();
libraw_processed_image_t* image = rawProcessor.dcraw_make_mem_image(&ret2);

float xres=72.0;
CImg<unsigned char> cimgOriginal(image->data,image->width,image->height, true);
cimgOriginal.shift(10*(-1), 10*(-1),0,0,0);
cimgOriginal.rotate(360.0-5, (float) 1200, (float) 800,0,0);
cimgOriginal.save_tiff("file.tiff", 0, &xres,0,false);
```

[image]

Thanks!

Mike

Comment: I think `libraw` does Bayer-decoding for you when you call `dcraw.process()` so you'll actually have `RGBRGBRGB...` which is called *"packed RGB"*. The format the CImg uses `RRRRGGGGBBBB` is called *"planar"* format because it stores the full plane of red followed by the full plane of green, then blue pixels. So you can try Googling `packed to planar RGB conversion` but I think you'll have to just write 3 nested `for` loops iterating over height, then width, then channels and unpack them yourself.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks for the hint! I didn't know the terms packed and planar RGB. I assume I must copy parts of the buffer with memcpy to the new buffer in planar order. 
I update code here when I have a solution.

Comment: I don't think `memcpy()` will work because the input data are not contiguous. I think you'll need to allocate the full output array then use three nested `for` loops and do a pixel at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your help, Mark! In the meantime I've figured out that Cimg can do it from packed RGB to planar RGB - with a method called permute_axes(). The documentation about permute_axes() is very short but here is a good explanation:

https://www.codefull.org/2014/11/cimg-does-not-store-pixels-in-the-interleaved-format/

With the following code I was able to get the image in Cimg. The attached screenshots shows DNG on the left and the image exported to tiff from Cimg.The image with leaves (taken from here: https://www.kenrockwell.com/leica/m9/sample-photos-3.htm) is a 8 bit DNG. The second example (with mouse and pen) shows my 16 bit DNG from Pixel 5. The code works also with 16 bit DNG files:

```
LibRaw rawProcessor;
rawProcessor.imgdata.params.use_auto_wb         = 0;        // Auto white-Balance
rawProcessor.imgdata.params.use_camera_wb       = 1;        // Use camera WB instead
rawProcessor.imgdata.params.output_color        = 1;        // [0-6] Output colorspace (0=raw, 1=sRGB, 2=Adobe, 3=Wide, 4=ProPhoto, 5=XYZ, 6=ACES)
rawProcessor.imgdata.params.no_auto_bright      = 0;        // No automatic brightnes

// Open the file and read the metadata
rawProcessor.open_file("L1004220.DNG");

// The metadata are accessible through data fields of the class
int w = rawProcessor.imgdata.sizes.width;
int h = rawProcessor.imgdata.sizes.height;
printf("Image size: %d x %d\n",w,h);

// Let us unpack the image
rawProcessor.unpack();

int  ret2=rawProcessor.dcraw_process();
libraw_processed_image_t* image = rawProcessor.dcraw_make_mem_image(&ret2);

float xres=72.0;
CImg<unsigned char> cimgOriginal(image->data, 3, w, h, 1, true);
cimgOriginal.permute_axes("yzcx");
cimgOriginal.save_tiff("L1004220.DNG.tiff", 0,
                       &xres,0,true);
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Cool - well done! I have seen that function mentioned before but it was always completely unclear to me what it does. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thanks Mark, the name of the function doesn't really say what it does. permut_axes() is a bad name for converting and could be much clearer. But anyway, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`libraw` stores pixels in *"packed"* (a.k.a. *"interleaved"*) format. So a 3x2 image will be stored like this:

```
R G B R G B R G B R G B R G B R G B
```

`CImg`, on the other hand, stores pixels in *"planar"* format, which bunches all the red pixels together in a plane, followed by all the green, then all the blue ones. So that same 3x2 image will be stored like this:

```
R R R R R R G G G G G G B B B B B B
```

---

I haven't done any C++ for years, so my code will be shockingly awful quality, but it does work at least:

```
#include "libraw/libraw.h"
#define cimg_display  0
#include "CImg.h"
using namespace cimg_library;
int main(int ac, char *av[])
{
        // Let us create an image processor
        LibRaw rawProcessor;

        // Open the file and read the metadata
        rawProcessor.open_file("image.dng");

        // The metadata are accessible through data fields of the class
        int w = rawProcessor.imgdata.sizes.width;
        int h = rawProcessor.imgdata.sizes.height;
        printf("Image size: %d x %d\n",w,h);

        // Let us unpack the image
        rawProcessor.unpack();

        int  ret2=rawProcessor.dcraw_process();
        libraw_processed_image_t* image = rawProcessor.dcraw_make_mem_image(&ret2);

        // Create buffer that CImg can use
        unsigned char * buffer;
        buffer = new unsigned char [w * h *3];

        // Pointer to the buffer from libraw where our data currently is
        unsigned char *p = image->data;

        // Pointers into the planar buffer for CImg
        unsigned char* Rp = buffer;
        unsigned char* Gp = buffer + h * w;
        unsigned char* Bp = buffer + 2 * h * w;

        // Unpack the packed pixel ino R, G and B planes
        for(int pixel=0; pixel<=w*h; pixel++){
            *Rp++ = *p++;
            *Gp++ = *p++;
            *Bp++ = *p++;
        }

        // Convert RGB packed raw image to planar format CImg in buffer
        CImg<unsigned char> cimgOriginal(buffer, w, h, 1, 3,true);
        float xres = 72;
        cimgOriginal.save_tiff("result.tif", 0, &xres, 0,false);
        rawProcessor.recycle();
        return 0;
}
```

Compiled on Raspberry Pi OS with:

```
g++ -O3 main.cpp -L /usr/local/lib -I /usr/local/include -lraw -I CImg
```

I tested it by downloading the first DNG sample picture from Ken Rockwell, [here](https://www.kenrockwell.com/leica/m9/sample-photos-3.htm).